# Rails internationalization messages with expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I need to evaluate some expression inside locale message string. It is not a kind of parameter, because its value is inside apps config, but it's kind of expression, so I don't need it to be hard coded inside message. Also, parameter doesn't suit me because, message is showed by third-party's gem controller, not my controller. So, I need something like this to be properly evaluated:

```
I18n.t(:taken_in_past, scope: [:errors, :messages])
```

**.yml file:**

```
en:
  errors:
      messages:
        taken_in_past: "could not be equal to on of #{Devise.password_archiving_count} previous passwords"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only idea, I don't check it in practice.

You can set handler for missing interpolations https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/config.rb#L107

In your locale you set

```
taken_in_past: "could not be equal to on of #{password_archiving_count} previous passwords"
```

and in handler you replace this interpolation

```
case key
when 'password_archiving_count' then Devise.password_archiving_count
```

Comment: Where should I place this handler and how to implement it?